# Is every group homomorphism of the rationals an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that every non trivial group homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q$ is a group isomorphism. The trivial homomorphism being the map that sends every rational to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Show that if $h:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$ is a group homomorphism, then $h(q)=qh(1)$ for every $q\in\Bbb Q$. You might want to begin by showing it for $q\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: so if $h(1)\not = 0$ then $h$ is obviously a group isomorphism. Does this generalize to every group homomorphism $\mathbb Q\oplus \mathbb Q\rightarrow \mathbb Q\oplus \mathbb Q$?

Comment: @palio: Such a homomorphism is completely determined by $h(\langle 0,1\rangle)$ and $h(\langle 1,0\rangle)$, but it can collapse the range to a copy of $\Bbb Q$: consider $h(\langle p,q\rangle)=\langle p,0\rangle$.